# Except link with Javascript

Tags: javascript

can you help me?

I'm trying to get this code below to make a excesão links in case the variable would be

```
var except_link = "blogspot.com, wordpress.com";
```

But it is only making excesão of 'blogspot.com'

thank you

```js
var except_link = "blogspot.com, wordpress.com";

var allow_file = ".3gp,.7z,.aac,.ac3,.asf,.asx,.avi,.bzip,.divx,.doc,.exe,.flv,.jpg,.png,.gz,.gzip,.iso,.jar,.jav,.mid,.mkv,.mov,.mp3,.mp4,.mpeg,.mpg,.msi,.nrg,.ogg,.pdf,.ppt,.psd,.rar,.rm,.rmvb,.rtf,.swf,.tar,.tar.gz,.tgz,.torrent,.ttf,.txt,.wav,.wma,.wmv,.xls,.zip,180upload,1fichier,1filesharing,2shared,4files,4share,4shared,a2zupload,adf,adrive,adv,amazo,";

except_link = (link_except != null) ? link_except : except_link;

function check(siteurl) {
  if ("" + allow_file != "undefined" && allow_file != "" && allow_file.replace(/\s/g, "") != "" && siteurl != "") {
    if ((" " + allow_file).indexOf(",") > 0) {
      pular = allow_file.split(",")
    } else {
      pular = new Array(allow_file)
    }
    for (s = 0; s < pular.length; s++) {
      if ((" " + siteurl.toLowerCase()).indexOf(pular[s].toLowerCase()) > 0) {
        if ("" + except_link != "undefined" && except_link != "" && except_link.replace(/\s/g, "") != "" && siteurl != "") {
          if ((" " + except_link).indexOf(",") > 0) {
            pular = except_link.split(",")
          } else {
            pular = new Array(except_link)
          }
          for (s = 0; s < pular.length; s++) {
            if ((" " + siteurl.toLowerCase()).indexOf(pular[s].toLowerCase()) > 0) {
              return false;
              break
            }
          }
          return true
        } else {
          return true
        }
      }
    }
    return false
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: You're splitting based on `","` where you are delimiting with `", "` (comma followed by space). Could the problem be that it doesn't match since the second URL will be `" wordpress.com"` (wordpress.com with a space in front of it)?

Comment: Yes, it's work, but without space? can you help me?

Comment: Either do `.split(", ")` or make your string `"blogSpot.com,wordpress.com"`

Comment: done, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting based on "," where you are delimiting with ", " (comma followed by space). The problem could be that it doesn't match since the second URL in the split array will be " wordpress.com" (wordpress.com with a space in front of it).

To remedy this, you could either change your split function to split accordingly:

```
except_link = "blogspot.com, wordpress.com" // comma-space
...
except_link.split(", ") // comma-space
```

Or, change your input string to accommodate your split requirements:

```
except_link = "blogspot.com,wordpress.com" // comma, no space
...
except_link.split(",") // comma, no space
```